# FileSystemException: Cannot copy file (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2) Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to copy a picked image file from the image_picker flutter plugin but I get the following exception in doing so. I am not getting why this exception is thrown. The copy method should create a file to the given destination path. Any help is appreciated.

My code

```
 XFile? pickedImage;
    // pick image from gallery
    pickedImage =
        await picker.pickImage(source: source, maxHeight: 1000, maxWidth: 1000);
    // stop excution if no image was picked
    if (pickedImage == null) return;

    final Directory appDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String appDirectoryPath = appDirectory.path;

    File copiedImage = await File(pickedImage.path)
        .copy('$appDirectoryPath/images/${p.basename(pickedImage.path)}');

    print(copiedImage.path);
```

Following exception is thrown:

```
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to '/data/user/0/com.example.vowpos.vowpos/app_flutter/images/scaled_image_picker5252314468419082258.jpg', path = '/data/user/0/com.example.vowpos.vowpos/cache/scaled_image_picker5252314468419082258.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
E/flutter (13288): #0      _File.copy.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:328:9)
E/flutter (13288): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13288): #1      SingleProductController.addImage (package:VowPOS/controllers/single_product_controller.dart:67:24)
E/flutter (13288): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13288): #2      SingleProductImagesScreen.showImageSelectionBottomSheet.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:VowPOS/ui/products/screens/single_product_images_screen.dart:331:19)
E/flutter (13288): <asynchronous suspension>
```

app/asr/main/AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test">
   <application
        android:label="test"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Does the directoy exist in which you wanna create a file? Check before and create if needed.

Comment: Yes directory ```$appDirectoryPath/images/${p.basename(pickedImage.path)}``` doesn't exist. But could you share the solution to copying files if the directory doesn't exist in the installed app directory.

Comment: As said before: if the directory does not exist then create the directory. If you are finally sure that the directory exists copy the file.

Answer (score 0):

try to add *.extenstion of the file name after copy to destination.

**flutter.png**

```
File file = File('${directory.path}/flutter.png');



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" //Add this Line
    android:label="@string/app_name">

---------<Activity, Sevices or Recivers>----------

</application>
```

Comment: I want the same name as image_picker has named for the file with extension. So I used path package to get the name of the picked file with extension.

import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

Comment: yes, you can use the same name, it's just an example of what you can try to solve the issue facing.

Comment: As per [path](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-path_path/basename.html) library, basename function returns file name along with extension in `$appDirectoryPath/images/${p.basename(pickedImage.path)}`

It is also evident in the exception thrown.

I believe it is related to non-existing `/data/user/0/com.example.vowpos.vowpos/app_flutter/images/` directory. But could you inform me how to copy a file to the non-existent directory?

Comment: if directory not exist then you have to create it first then check whether it is available or not